# How to hide/disable ::marker pseudo-element for safari

Tags: css, wordpress, pseudo-element, marker

I have one problem. I can't hide ::marker for safari.

`#categories-4.widget_categories::marker { content: '' !important; }`

It works fine for example for chrome or microsoft edge. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're looking for `list-style`, not `:marker`.

Comment: a bit of html too would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I had to use both `list-style-type: none` as well as `padding: 0` for Chrome & Safari on MacOS Ventura.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: No effect on Safari 17.3.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
::-webkit-details-marker {   display:none; }
```

Comment: No effect on Safari 17.3.

Answer (score 1):

For summary and ul:

```
ul,
summary {
    list-style-type: none;
}
summary::marker {
    color:#fff;
    z-index:-5;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_list-style-type_ex

---

Comment: No effect on Safari 17.3.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS and it should work.

```
#categories-4.widget_categories
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: No effect on Safari 17.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
  summary {

    text-indent: -1em;
    padding-left: 1em; /* adjust accordingly to your layout */
  }

  /* Chrome etc */
  summary::marker {
    
    color: transparent;
  }

  /* Safari */
  summary::-webkit-details-marker {

    color: transparent;
  }
```

Alternative (not thoroughly tested)

```
  summary {

     display: block;
  }

  summary::-webkit-details-marker {

     display: none;
  }
```